# Bar Mitzva בו ביום on Shabbes - when to start putting on Tefilin?

Tags: shabbat, minhag, tefilin, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah

Multiple customs of when to start putting on tefilin exist, one of such being to start the day a boy turns 13. If that day occurs on Shabbes, are there any customs to begin putting on Tefillin on the Friday before? This is something I have heard people mentioning.

Comment: I didn't realize there were some who put tefillin on that late, I thought hanoches tefillin was a few months before bar mitzva

Answer (score 2):

Nitei Gavriel - Bar Mitzvah discusses this. He mentions that there are those that will wait until Sunday, those that will start of Friday, and those that will start Friday without a Bracha.

https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46541&st=&pgnum=233